# fork not supported for subinterpreters error in production

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I have deployed a Django project to production that fails to handle requests properly due to python multiprocess in my backend script. The problem is in my contact form in the webpage, where user should input name, email and a message they will like to send. Once they click on send the message, a recaptcha is performed and if that returns true, the message will be sent via email using Python's multiprocess. So the process looks like

user input message form -> message form post -> reCaptha check -> if passed -> multiprocess to send the message via an email

Everything worked fine when tested in development mode, but in deployment with apache2 I receive the following error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://www.dimsum.dk/hdnytorv

Django Version: 3.1.3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/index/views.py", line 146, in post
    emailObject = sendEmail(form = form,
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website/Modules/emailMessage.py", line 40, in __init__
    p1.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 70, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /hdnytorv
Exception Value: fork not supported for subinterpreters
```

When I serched in the documentation for [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html) I realized that this is most likely caused by my use of Python's multiprocess in the backend. As web server I am using apache2 with the below configuration

```
[Wed Mar 17 05:25:51.489125 2021] [core:warn] [pid 50605] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-08-12T19:46:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:88
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

I am not sure how to configure apache2 or mod_wsgi properly to solve this problem. Also what will be the best practice for such a problem? The reason why I use multiprocess is because I wish to give user a smooth experience in the web not needing to wait for the backend to complete the email sending process which can take some seconds. Therefore after validated with recaptcha the user gets a message the email is sent successfully, while another process is in the background handling the actual email sending.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and can be solved using mod_wsgi. This video is very helpful and provides explaination on how to setup mod_wsgi. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPz0s1CQsTE&t=6s